# Calculate discount between weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table containing product price data, like that:

```
ProductId   RecordDate                  Price
46          2015-01-17 14:35:05.533     112.00
47          2015-01-17 14:35:05.533     88.00
45          2015-01-17 14:35:05.533     134.00
```

I have been able to group data by week and product, with this query:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [RecordDate]), 0) AS [Week], ProductId, MIN([Price]) AS [MinimumPrice]
FROM [dbo].[ProductPriceHistory]
GROUP BY DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [RecordDate]), 0), ProductId
ORDER BY ProductId, [Week]
```

obtaining this result:

```
Week                       Product    Price
2015-01-12 00:00:00.000    1          99.00
2015-01-19 00:00:00.000    1          98.00
2015-01-26 00:00:00.000    1          95.00
2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    1          95.00
2015-02-09 00:00:00.000    1          95.00
2015-02-16 00:00:00.000    1          95.00
2015-02-23 00:00:00.000    1          80.00
2015-03-02 00:00:00.000    1          97.00
2015-03-09 00:00:00.000    1          85.00
2015-01-12 00:00:00.000    2          232.00
2015-01-19 00:00:00.000    2          233.00
2015-01-26 00:00:00.000    2          194.00
2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    2          194.00
2015-02-09 00:00:00.000    2          199.00
2015-02-16 00:00:00.000    2          199.00
2015-02-23 00:00:00.000    2          199.00
2015-03-02 00:00:00.000    2          214.00
```

Now for each product I'd like to get the difference between the last two week values, so that I can calculate the discount. I don't know how to write this as a SQL Query!

EDIT:
Expected output would be something like that:

```
Product    Price
1          -12.00
2          15.00
```

Thank you!

Comment: How big is your table `ProductPriceHistory`? How many different `ProductId`s do you have? Do you have a separate table with the list of all products? I'm asking these questions, because if you have a separate table `Products` and it is relatively small and if `ProductPriceHistory` is relatively large and if you can create an appropriate index, then I think it is possible to write a much more efficient query, than suggested by @NoDisplayName.

Comment: You are right, @NoDisplayName. I was thinking about using `CROSS APPLY` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`. Also, using `CROSS APPLY` you don't need `LEAD` or `LAG` and you don't need to `GROUP BY DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [RecordDate]), 0)`. You don't need to scan the whole table, you can seek and find just those elements that are needed for each product. If number of products is small it may be much faster than reading the whole product history.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Products table is relatively small compared to ProductPriceHistory table!

Answer (score 2):

since you are using Sql Server 2014 you can use `LAG` or `LEAD` window function to do this.

Generate `Row number` to find the last two weeks for each `product`.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY product ORDER BY weeks DESC)rn 
         FROM   Yourtable) 
SELECT product, 
       price 
FROM   (SELECT product, 
               Price=price - Lead(price)OVER(partition BY product ORDER BY rn) 
        FROM   cte a 
        WHERE  a.rn <= 2) A 
WHERE  price IS NOT NULL
```

- [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8bbad/6)

Traditional solution, can be used before `Sql server 2012`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY product
                    ORDER BY weeks DESC)rn
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT a.Product,
       b.Price - a.Price
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.Product = b.Product
                 AND a.rn = b.rn + 1
WHERE  a.rn <= 2
       AND b.Product IS NOT NULL
```